# No audio no matter what device I connect!

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

My sound is not working... Internal audio? Nope! Headphones? Nope... Nothing! I have looked through all the audio settings and nothing has worked! I cant watch YouTube videos without audio! However, There is one sound that works... And that's the volume up and down sound!

**Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this! I forgot that the specific app I was using was muted... For some reason!